# printing with RGB background

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I know its possible to print RGB colored text like so:

```
def colored(r, g, b, text):
    return "\033[38;2;{};{};{}m{} \033[39m".format(r, g, b, text)


text = "Hello, World"
colored_text = colored(132, 204, 247, text)
print(colored_text)
```

But, is there a way to print with RGB colored **background**?

Cuz, as far as I know, there are a few kinda built-in background colors for printing. But I want to be able to use rgb codes and get the appropriate background color for the printed text.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: according to https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2020/03/28/terminal-colors.html, you can replace 38 by 48 to change the bg color (not tested).

Comment: @qouify you could put it as answer. You could copy some information from link to your answer and add minimal working code for this.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the suggestion.  I just added it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to
https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2020/03/28/terminal-colors.html#ansi-escape-codes-for-terminal-graphics
the *Select Graphic Rendition* parameter following the `'\033['` (the
*Control Sequence Inducer*) to be used to define the background color
is `48;2;r;g;b`.

So here is `colored_background` that returns the text parameter with
the given background color:

```py
def colored_background(r, g, b, text):
    return f'\033[48;2;{r};{g};{b}m{text}\033[0m'

text = "What a nice red background!"
colored_text = colored_background(255, 0, 0, text)
print(colored_text)
```

You can naturally combine both:

```py
def colored(fg_color, bg_color, text):
    r, g, b = fg_color
    result = f'\033[38;2;{r};{g};{b}m{text}'
    r, g, b = bg_color
    result = f'\033[48;2;{r};{g};{b}m{result}\033[0m'
    return result

text = "What a nice blue text with a red background!"
colored_text = colored((0, 0, 255), (255, 0, 0), text)
print(colored_text)
```

Note that here you only need one escape sequence with parameter 0 as this
one resets both the foreground and the background colors to their
default.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using **Curses** module, it helps you to style apps running on command line.

[Tech with Tim on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Db4oc8qc9RU) has a tutorial for that. you'll find all what you need for coloring texts and backgrounds.

Comment: yeah thanks. it has been hanging around in my recommended for quite some time now. might as well check it out :)

Answer (score 2):

this will do:

```
"\u001b[48;2;{};{};{}m{} \u001b[0m".format(r, g, b, text)
```

A helpful recourse I found:
https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html#background-colors

Comment: thanks. although this does work fine in the vs code terminal, the macOS built in terminal doesn’t give a damn to the background colors :(